rvest to scrape images
I've worked on this for couple of weeks without success. My long term goal is to scrape each image from the following website (link:https://bioguide.congress.gov/search). For starters, I'm trying to get just one location of the image stored in the 'img alt' property of the html code.
The html code shows this
<div class="l-grid__item l-grid__item--3/12 l-grid__item--12/12@mobile--sm l-grid__item--4/12@desktop l-grid__item--6/12@tablet"><div tabindex="0" class="c-card u-flex u-flex--column u-height--100% u-cursor--pointer u-bxs--dark-lg:hover c-card--@print"><div class="u-height--100% u-width--100% u-p u-flex u-flex--centered u-mb--auto"><div aria-hidden="true" class="u-max-width--80% u-max-height--250px"><img alt="/photo/66c88d1d7401a93215e0b225.jpg" class="u-max-height--250px u-height--auto u-width--auto u-block" src="/photo/66c88d1d7401a93215e0b225.jpg"></div></div><div class="u-flex u-flex--column u-flex--no-shrink u-p u-bg--off-white u-fw--bold u-color--primary u-text--center u-bt--light-gray"><div class="u-cursor--pointer u-mb--xs">AANDAHL, Fred George</div><div class="u-fz--sm u-fw--semibold">1897 – 1966</div></div></div></div>

I used the following R code but I get character(0)
library(httr)
library(rvest)

# Fetch the HTML content with a custom User-Agent
response <- GET("https://bioguide.congress.gov/search", 
                user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36"))

# Parse the content
page <- read_html(content(response, as = "text", encoding = "UTF-8"))

# Navigate to the div with class starting with 'l-grid__item' and extract img alt attributes
img_alt_values <- page %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "//div[starts-with(@class, 'l-grid__item')]") %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = ".//img") %>%
  html_attr("alt")

Can anyone suggest how I get past this?

The image links do not appear in the html returned from your GET request. The page you see in your browser is built dynamically using JavaScript. You could reproduce all the steps required to get these links using only http requests, but it would be lengthy and complicated. It is likely to be easier to use RSelenium or similar.

@AllanCameron I've tried the Rselenium route before but it didn't pave a path forward, either. So I resorted back to this. How sure are you that rvest is not a viable option here?

It's viable, but if you look in your browser's console you will see that quite a lot of xhr requests need to be made to set up the request that would ultimately return the json file that contains the actual image urls. You could work through it if  you have the time. Hit F12 in your browser, open the network panel , clear it and navigate to the page. You will see the requests you will need to emulate  to get the data.

Having a look at the network traffic it can be seen that the data is returned from an API where the page's search function generates a POST request with a JSON payload. We can use httr2 to make these requests and return up to 100 records at a time, although to make things more minimal I limit each request to 3 records in the code below.
The url and payload are:
library(httr2)
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)

# API address
url <- "https://app-elastic-prod-eus2-001.azurewebsites.net/search"

# JSON payload  
payload_string <- r"({
    "index": "bioguideprofiles",
    "aggregations": [
        {
            "field": "jobPositions.congressAffiliation.congress.name",
            "subFields": [
                "jobPositions.congressAffiliation.congress.startDate",
                "jobPositions.congressAffiliation.congress.endDate"
            ]
        },
        {
            "field": "jobPositions.congressAffiliation.partyAffiliation.party.name"
        },
        {
            "field": "jobPositions.job.name"
        },
        {
            "field": "jobPositions.congressAffiliation.represents.regionCode"
        }
    ],
    "size": 12,
    "from": 0,
    "sort": [
        {
            "_score": true
        },
        {
            "field": "unaccentedFamilyName",
            "order": "asc"
        },
        {
            "field": "unaccentedGivenName",
            "order": "asc"
        },
        {
            "field": "unaccentedMiddleName",
            "order": "asc"
        }
    ],
    "keyword": "",
    "filters": {

    },
    "matches": [

    ],
    "searchType": "OR",
    "applicationName": "bioguide.house.gov"
}
)"

We need to convert the payload to an R list so we can easily modify the from argument in the request with req_body_json_modify():
# Convert to R list
payload_list <- fromJSON(payload_string)

# Get n records of first x records
request_size <- 3L         # 100 max per request
total_records <- 15L       # 12953 records in database
from <- seq(1L, total_records, request_size) - 1L  # Sequence of starting positions

# Generate base request
req <- request(url) |>
    req_method("POST") |>
    req_body_json(payload_list) 

# Generate list of requests (5 requests of 3 records each)
requests <- from |> 
   lapply(\(n) req |> req_body_json_modify(from = n, size = request_size))

# Execute requests
responses <- req_perform_sequential(requests, on_error = "return")

# Parse responses and extract image URL
results <- resps_data(
  responses,
  \(r) r |>
    resp_body_json(simplifyDataFrame = TRUE) |>
    pluck("filteredHits")  |>
    select(starts_with("unaccented"), any_of("image"))
  ) |>
  bind_rows() |>
  hoist("image", "contentUrl") |> 
  select(-image) |> 
  mutate(image_url = ifelse(is.na(contentUrl), NA, paste0("https://bioguide.congress.gov/photo/", basename(contentUrl))), .keep = "unused") |> 
  as_tibble()

Where results contains the derived image URLs:
# A tibble: 15 × 4
   unaccentedFamilyName unaccentedGivenName unaccentedMiddleName image_url                                       
   <chr>                <chr>               <chr>                <chr>                                           
 1 Aandahl              Fred                George               https://bioguide.congress.gov/photo/66c88d1d740…
 2 Abbitt               Watkins             Moorman              https://bioguide.congress.gov/photo/ad79716f164…
 3 Abbot                Joel                NA                   NA                                              
 4 Abbott               Amos                NA                   NA                                              
 5 Abbott               Joseph              Carter               https://bioguide.congress.gov/photo/39253c461f2…
 6 Abbott               Joseph              NA                   https://bioguide.congress.gov/photo/43ba0fd5299…
 7 Abbott               Josiah              Gardner              https://bioguide.congress.gov/photo/470dc5df4ba…
 8 Abbott               Nehemiah            NA                   NA                                              
 9 Abdnor               James               NA                   https://bioguide.congress.gov/photo/a32ba2ea44f…
10 Abel                 Hazel               Hempel               https://bioguide.congress.gov/photo/07f3a896ce1…
11 Abele                Homer               E.                   https://bioguide.congress.gov/photo/a58aa67c32f…
12 Abercrombie          James               NA                   NA                                              
13 Abercrombie          John                William              https://bioguide.congress.gov/photo/76a90e5795f…
14 Abercrombie          Neil                NA                   https://bioguide.congress.gov/photo/66cbb14989f…
15 Abernethy            Charles             Laban                https://bioguide.congress.gov/photo/00ff9ca93d0…

There is a heap of other data returned with each query but will leave how to wrangle it all to you.

There is an insurmountable amount of logic in your response that's beyond my knowledge and skillset. It's frustrating to realize how much more there is learn in R. Nonetheless, it goes without saying how much your response, and the time you took to draft it, helps me. Thanks and much appreciated. Accepting your answer.
